# Mock: SetReturnsDefault for async methods always return null

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, mocking, moq

I want to mock a service to always return a default object.
I tried this but it still always return null:

```cs
var service = new Mock<MyService>();            
service.SetReturnsDefault(Task.FromResult(new ServiceResult<object>
{
  Status = ResultStatus.OK,
  Value = null
}));
```

The methods are async and return `Task<IServiceResult<object>>` where object can be any object (also a collection of objects).
`ServiceResult` implement the `IServiceResult` interface.
Why is it not working? I would like to avoid setup every method...

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT:**
I use for example a method like this but it result is always null instead of the default ServiceResult:

```cs
var result = await _service.GetEntityAssetUsagesAsync(EntityTypeEnum.Radio, radio.MediaChannelId);
```

Here is (a piece of) my interface:

```cs
Task<IServiceResult<List<EntityAssetUsageDto>>> GetEntityAssetUsagesAsync(EntityTypeEnum entityType, int entityId);

Task<IServiceResult<List<AssetDto>>> GetAssetsAsync(List<long> assetIds, bool withoutException = false);
```

Comment: Ok the update clears things up. This is a covariance-contravarience issue. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/

Comment: @Nkosi Could it be simply impossible?

Comment: For your generic application it may be.

Comment: @Nkosi Thanks for your time and the link. It helps me understand things. I will continue mocking needed methods without the SetReturnsDefault.